# Value is in enum list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, enums

I have a fairly basic question: How can I check if a given value is contained in a list of enum values?

For example, I have this enum:

```
public enum UserStatus
{
    Unverified,
    Active,
    Removed,
    Suspended,
    Banned
}
```

Now I want to check if `status in (Unverified, Active)`

I know this works:

```
bool ok = status == UserStatus.Unverified || status == UserStatus.Active;
```

But there has to be a more elegant way to write this.

The topic of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164425/determining-if-enum-value-is-in-list-c) is very similar, but that's dealing with flags enums, and this is not a flags enum.

Comment: What is the datatype of status variable?

Comment: @Lav The variable `status` is of type `UserStatus`.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Here is an extension method that helps a lot in a lot of circumstances.

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T val, params T[] values) where T : struct
    {
        return values.Contains(val);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(1.In(2, 1, 3));
Console.WriteLine(1.In(2, 3));
Console.WriteLine(UserStatus.Active.In(UserStatus.Removed, UserStatus.Banned));
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Again, not sure why this isn't built-in, but at least it's possible. :)  Thanks!

Comment: This is a very nice approach!

Comment: Beautiful code... had no idea that the `this` type parameter of an extension method could be generic.

Comment: .NET 4.0+ has a built-in function for this, `Enum.HasFlag(Enum)`. In this example, you can use it like, `bool ok = (UserStatus.Unverified | UserStatus.Active).HasFlag(status);`. More here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61389498/4294275

Comment: Okay.  I'm sorry.  Really basic question.  Where would this code belong?

Answer (score 35):

If it is a longer list of enums, you can use:

```
var allowed = new List<UserStatus> { UserStatus.Unverified, UserStatus.Active };
bool ok = allowed.Contains(status);
```

Otherwise there is no way around the long `||` predicate, checking for each allowed value.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Enum.IsDefined`

example:

```
public enum enStage {Work, Payment, Record, Return, Reject};
int StageValue = 4;

Enum.IsDefined(typeof(enStage), StageValue)
```

Comment: Can't see how this checks against 2 out of 5 values

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in .NET 4.0+ using [Enum.HasFlag(Enum)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag) method,

```
UserStatus status = UserStatus.Unverified; // just assumed status is Unverified

bool ok = (UserStatus.Unverified | UserStatus.Active).HasFlag(status);
```

You can also do the same by assigning into a variable like,

```
UserStatus status = UserStatus.Active; // just assumed status is Active

UserStatus unverifiedOrActive = UserStatus.Unverified | UserStatus.Active;

bool ok = unverifiedOrActive.HasFlag(status);
```

Comment: This only works, if the enum values are actually flags (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a method to encapsulate it?

```
public bool UnVerifiedOrActive(User user)
{
    return (user.UserStatus == UserStatus.Unverified || 
            user.UserStatus == UserStatus.Active);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really a matter of DRY, just more about concise code.  I'm still not sure why C# doesn't have some sort of `in` operator that can be used for cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
UserStatus userStatus = null;
Eum.TryParse<UserStatus>(status.ToString(), out userStatus);

if(userStatus != null)
{
  //it is not in the list
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, as it is checking against every value in the enum, rather than a subset of values (if I'm reading correctly).

Comment: @Jerad this works. give it a try. I have the same solution as what `Lav` posted

Comment: @Avian - but where do you check for just Unverified or Active values (vs. the other three values)?

Comment: @Jerad. my bad. answering questions from the office didn't give me much time reading your question.

Comment: @Avian - I understand, no problem.  Thanks for the attempt nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
UserStatus ustatus;
if(Enum.TryParse<UserStatus>(c.ToString(), out ustatus))
{
 ..Your logic
}
```