# in operator in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, enums

I think there was an *in* operator in Commodore 128 Basic.
Is there an in operator in c# too?

I mean is there an operator of kind

```
if(aString in ["a", "b", "c"])  
  Console.Out.WriteLine("aString is 'a', 'b' or 'c'");
```

Edit1: Currently I need it to decide if an enum value is in a range of some enum values.

Edit2: Thank you all for the Contains() solutions. I will use it in the future. But currently I have a need for enum values. Can I replace the following statement with Contains() or other methods?

```
public enum MyEnum { A, B, C }

class MyEnumHelper
{
  void IsSpecialSet(MyEnum e)
  {
    return e in [MyEnum.A, MyEnum.C]
  }
}
```

Edit3: Sorry it was not Basic. I just googled a while and found Turbo Pascal as a candidate where I could saw it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29#Set_types

Edit4: **Best answers up to now (end of 15 Feb 2012):**

- For lists and arrays: accepted answer and all other answers with
  *Contains()* solutions
- For Enums: TheKaneda's answer with good list of pros/cons for
  different extension methods

Comment: Based on your code, you're looking to see if aString is equal to "a", "b", or "c", not whether it contains "a", "b", or "c".  is that right?  It's been years siunce I looked at Commodor 128 basic, but this look like typical branching code to me if I remember correctly.

Comment: I don't recall that from C-128 BASIC (though you take me back...) but that is very close to python syntax

Comment: Yeah, no `in` in any 1980s BASIC that I can remember.

Comment: @dav I mean the **equal** thing not the contains thing.

Comment: Or, re: @AndrewHare's answer, you can do: `return new[] { MyEnum.A, MyEnum.C }.Contains(e);`. Alternatively, with the linked extension method in my comment: `return e.In(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.C);`

Comment: @ma It was my mistake. I knew it from Turbo Pascal. I updated my question, see Edit3.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It was my mistake. I knew it from Turbo Pascal. I updated my question, see Edit3.

Comment: @TheKaneda Thanks. The extension method is very interesting. Trevor Pilley's answer is in that direction.

Comment: @brgerner Added answer explaining the difference between the three extension method approaches.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(new [] {"a", "b", "c"}.Contains(aString))  
    Console.Out.WriteLine("aString is 'a', 'b' or 'c'");
```

This uses the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) method to search the array for `aString`.

Comment: Is there a related solution for enums?

Comment: @brgerner: For a bit of syntactic sugar (which has pros and cons), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5320727/1169696 - allows you to do `if (MyEnumValue.In(MyEnum.First, MyEnum.Second, MyEnum.Third)) { ... }`

Comment: @the If it were possible to assign your extension method only to my enumeration it were perfect.

Comment: Update to my last comment: Trevor Pilley's answer solves that problem.

Comment: Not my extension method, but it is possible. Adding an answer, since it takes space to demonstrate. Don't accept it, though - since we're far from your original question, that wouldn't be "fair".

Comment: I am curious how it impacts performance? Does it create an array or something or it's just IEnumerable which should be optimal?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to my Delphi days, I'm also used to its **in** keyword. For the generic case in C#, I'm using:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T t, params T[] args)
    {
      return args.Contains(t);
    }
  }
}
```

which can be utilized as follows:

```
  var color = Color.Aqua;
  var b = color.In(Color.Black, Color.Blue);
  b = "hello".In("hello", "world");
```

Answer (score 3):

No. You can come close:

```
if (new [] { "a", "b", "c" }.Contains(aString))
    Console.Out.WriteLine("aString is 'a', 'b' or 'c'");
```

Comment: @DavidStratton Actually I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

The equivelent in C# would be [`Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) (assuming you have a list or array of data)

```
var myStuff = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var aString = "a";

if(myStuff.Contains(aString)) {
    //Do Stuff
}
```

As for the [`in`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) keyword, it has a different use:

```
var myStuff = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var aString = "a";

foreach(string str in myStuff) {
    //Iteration 0 = a, 1 = b, 2 = c
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an extension method if you want a slightly more fluent way of working so for this example of a customer and customer status:

```
public enum CustomerStatus
{
    Active,
    Inactive,
    Deleted
}

public class Customer
{
    public CustomerStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

Use the following extension method:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static bool In(this Enum value, params Enum[] values)
    {
        return values.Contains(value);
    }
}
```

to allow you to write code like this:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
        var customer = new Customer
        {
            Status = CustomerStatus.Active
        };

        if (customer.Status.In(CustomerStatus.Active, CustomerStatus.Inactive))
        {
            // Do something.
        }
}
```

Comment: A generic extension method would be more useful: `public static bool In<T>(this T value, params T[] values) { return values.Contains(value); }`.

Comment: Yes that is true, I made it enum specific as that was what @brgerner asked about. Others have also posted examples using generics.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ("abc".Contains(aString[0])) 
  Console.WriteLine("aString is 'a', 'b' or 'c'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Most collections will have a .Contains method, and LINQ also has a Contains method, so anything that's enumerable that doesn't already have its own contains method gets one from LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you're looking to see if aString is equal to "a", "b", or "c", not whether it ***contains*** "a", "b", or "c".  If I'm reading the question right, then:

No. Instead, you'd use a switch statement

```
switch(aString)
{
   case "a:":
   case "b:":
   case "b:":
      Console.Out.WriteLine("aString is 'a', 'b' or 'c'"); 
   default:
      Console.Out.WriteLine("aString is NOT 'a', 'b' or 'c'"); 
}
```

Comment: But his question is written this way to demonstrate the way the inquirer wants to use the language, not the actual business purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the contains method:

```
string[] values = { "A", "B", "C" };

if (values.Contains("A"))           //True
    MessageBox.Show("A is there");

if (values.Contains("b"))               //false, strings are case sensitive
    MessageBox.Show("b is there");
```

Answer (score 1):

The in keyword is used with foreach only.
And no, there isn't such an operator dedicated for such purpose. But you can use built-in methods of the array type or list type as demonstrated below:

```
        string aString = "a";
        string[] strings = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
        if (strings.Contains(aString)) //Contains here is a Linq extension
            Console.WriteLine("aString is either a, b, or c");

        List<string> stringList = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
        if(stringList.Contains(aString)) //Contains here is a member method
            Console.WriteLine("aString is either a, b, or c");

        if(stringList.IndexOf(aString) != -1)
            Console.WriteLine("aString is either a, b, or c");
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer a follow-up question on Andrew Hare's answer, yes it's possible to restrict the `In` extension method to a single enum. Don't accept this answer, since Andrew and Trevor answered the revised question (and most answered the original... anyway).

To recap, this is what I find most useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5320727/1169696

But if you really want to restrict it, that's just a matter of using the Enum's type as parameter instead of a generic (or Enum):

```
// This is the one we want to use our In extension method on:
public enum FriendlyEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public enum EnemyEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
}

// The extension method:
public static class FriendlyEnumExtensions
{
    public static bool In(this FriendlyEnum value, params FriendlyEnum[] list)
    {
        return list.Contains(value);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FriendlyEnum friendlyValue = FriendlyEnum.A;
        EnemyEnum enemyValue       = EnemyEnum.A;

        // Outputs "True":
        Console.WriteLine(friendlyValue.In(FriendlyEnum.A, FriendlyEnum.C));

        // Outputs "False":
        Console.WriteLine(friendlyValue.In(FriendlyEnum.B, FriendlyEnum.C));

        // All of these will result in compiler errors, 
        // because EnemyEnum is invading some way or another:
        Console.WriteLine(friendlyValue.In(EnemyEnum.A, EnemyEnum.B));
        Console.WriteLine(enemyValue.In(FriendlyEnum.A, FriendlyEnum.B));
        Console.WriteLine(enemyValue.In(EnemyEnum.A, EnemyEnum.B));
    }

}
```

I find it less useful than the generic one I linked - or Trevor's approach - but there you go.

**Update**

Difference between the approaches:

- Using Trevor's method, all three mixes of enemy and friend in the code above will be accepted by the compiler (the output will be "True", "False", "False", "False", "True").
- Using the generic approach, the last one will be accepted (and "True"), because the generics only ensure that all parameters (including `this`) are of the same type. I.e., it won't accept mixing different enums in the same call.
- The one above, again, will only accept the one enum you've designed the extension method for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has proposed `switch`:

```
class MyEnumHelper 
{ 
    void IsSpecialSet(MyEnum e) 
    { 
        return e in [MyEnum.A, MyEnum.C] 
        switch (e)
        {
            case MyEnum.A:
            case MyEnum.C:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    } 
}
```