# if condition with each item in array

Tags: c#

My English is not good. So i tired to write if condition with each item in array. What is solution for this. Thank you for you help
This code make me tired , so how to do it like this

```
public bool AllowElement(Element element)// element is object by mouse houver on Revit program
    {
        BuiltInCategory[] BIC  = new BuiltInCategory[]{Frame, Column, Slab,Foundation, etc...}// BIC is 
        in enum, and this is declare with params key word
        if( ele ==  (int)BIC.Frame || ele ==  (int)BIC.Column ||
            ele ==  (int)BIC.Slab || ele ==  (int)BIC.Foundation ||
            ele == (int)BIC.etc....)
        {
            return true
        }
    }
```

end this code I writed but i feel it not true

```
public bool AllowElement(Element element)
    {
        int ele = element.Category.Id.IntegerValue;
        foreach (var item in BIC)
        {
            if (ele == (int)item)
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hard to tell hat your asking based on your sample, You could try Exists, IndexOf, for an Array or if it's an Enum than IsDefined

Comment: But how to nest a condition into an array?.

Comment: I'm not understanding you, See the methods I cited above and edit your Question for clarity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value is in enum list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320592/value-is-in-enum-list)

Comment: You could use [`.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) to return a bool if any entry in the list matches a condition you specify.

Comment: Change the second code you have posted. If `BIC` is an enum then try `if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(BIC), ele)) { return true; }`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Linq for validating if the item exists?

```
    public bool AllowElement(Element element)
    {
        return BIC.Any(x => (int)x == element.Category.Id.IntegerValue);
    }
```

`Any()` method returns true if there is any element that matches the condition  [Microsoft docs on Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

This is with assumption that BIC is in scope of this method.